# Generic Method Json Parsing

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I have this generic method which is used for executing **Post** request and then parsing the response like this.

```
private async Task<object> PostAsync<T1,T2>(string uri, T2 content)
{
    using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri))
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
        using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {
            requestMessage.Content = stringContent;

            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Request Succeeded");

                T1 responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T1>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                return  responseModel;
            }
            else
            {
                return await GetFailureResponseModel(response);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the issue is that some Post request response are in **SnakeCase** and others are in **CamelCase**. How can I fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you know at compile-time when you know snake_case and when you need the default strategy, you could just do this:

```
private Task<object> PostAsync<T1, T2>(string uri, T2 content)
{
    return PostAsync<T1, T2>(uri, content, new DefaultNamingStrategy());
}

private async Task<object> PostAsync<T1, T2>(string uri, T2 content, NamingStragy namingStrategy)
{
    using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, uri))
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
        using (var stringContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
        {
            requestMessage.Content = stringContent;

            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Request Succeeded");

                var deserializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                    {
                        NamingStrategy = namingStrategy
                    }
                };

                T1 responseModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T1>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(), deserializerSettings);
                return responseModel;
            }
            else
            {
                return await GetFailureResponseModel(response);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, when you need the default strategy:

```
await PostAsync<Some1, Some2>(uri, some2Content);
```

and, when you need snake_case:

```
await PostAsync<Some1, Some2>(uri, some2Content, new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy());
```

Comment: @camiloTervinto I have already accepted your answer and implemented as well, But don't you think Passing naming strategy in Generic method is code smell?

Comment: @Shabirjan Not at all, this is a very common pattern and you can find many in the .NET Framework source code